# How to get notification for new available Wifi Network

Tags: windows, winapi, wifi, wlanapi

Is there a way to get a notification when a new Wifi Network has been detected?

I glanced through the Native Wifi API Reference and found the [WlanRegisterNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706771.aspx) function but I'm not sure if that includes what i am looking for. The remark does not mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `WlanRegisterNotification` is indeed the correct function. You need to do a little digging in the documentation to find exactly what each notification provides, by looking at [`WLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706278.aspx) (in the remarks section for `WlanRegisterNotification`), then [`WLAN_NOTIFICATION_ACM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815254.aspx)<sup>†</sup>. Specifically, you're looking for one of these two notifications:

- `wlan_notification_acm_network_available` Which gives a notification when a connectable network is detected, and you're not currently connected to another network, and there isn't an automatic connection available.
- `wlan_notification_acm_scan_list_refresh` (Windows 8+)

*<sup>†</sup> ACM stands for "auto configuration module"*